# Issues in syncing S3 bucket with django

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I wanted to sync my local static files with S# bucket but whenever I run collectstatic command , It do not detect any change in my local file and thus do not sync local static folder with S3 Bucket.

I am using django-storages-redux==1.3.1. 
and here are my settings :

```
STATICFILES_LOCATION = 'static'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'pathto.StaticStorage'
STATIC_URL = "https://%s.s3.amazonaws.com/%s/" % (AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME, STATICFILES_LOCATION)

MEDIAFILES_LOCATION = 'media'
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'pathto.MediaStorage'
MEDIA_URL = "https://%s.s3.amazonaws.com/%s/" % (AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME, MEDIAFILES_LOCATION)
```

## static and media storage class

```
class StaticStorage(S3BotoStorage):
    location = getattr(settings, 'STATICFILES_LOCATION', 'static')


class MediaStorage(S3BotoStorage):
    location = getattr(settings, 'MEDIAFILES_LOCATION', 'media')
```

Also I guess django-storgae is not compatible with Python3 . and I am using djnago1.8 and python3 . So is there any package which can work smoothly with django 1.8 and python3

Comment: If you can make a work around use `aws cli` . I had similar issues what I did was made a bash script on particular triggers

Comment: @NikhilParmar I am also thinking about the bash script , but rt now due to short time deadlines I thought may be collectstatic will do the job but I guess I was wrong :( . You have any tutorial or example that can help me in understanding

Comment: This [Link](https://aws.amazon.com/cli/) will clear all your doubts for `s3 sync`.For bash script just put that command in it and trigger it with your current code

Comment: @NikhilParmar ok I'll see. thx

Comment: @NikhilParmar yes it works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

As Nikhil suggests in his comments that it is better use **`aws cli`** instead of django packages. It is short and less complex

Aws [docummentation](https://aws.amazon.com/cli/)
Git [repo](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli) 
I have follwed git docs . Its more explained and clear (just what you need to sync S3 bucket)

Here is the command used to sync bucket  (I am syncing static folder)
`aws s3 sync static s3://storage-<bucket-name>/static --exclude *.tmp`

Also you need to configure aws before this command , how to configure aws is explained in the git repo I have mentioned above.

Comment: Hey it will be better if you post the code you are now using for everyone.!!